# Mercury with Xamp does not mail, but gives no error

Tags: email, php

Im making a website, and after users have registered i want to send them an email.
Im using the codeigniter framework which has some neat premade mail functions in it.
The code is working like it should, and when i run the php mail debugger it says this :

```
220 localhost ESMTP server ready. 
hello: 250-localhost Hello localhost; ESMTPs are:
250-TIME
250-SIZE 0
250 HELP
from: 250 Sender OK - send RCPTs.
to: 250 Recipient OK - send RCPT or DATA.
data: 354 OK, send data, end with CRLF.CRLF
250 Data received OK. 
quit: 221 localhost Service closing channel.
Your message has been successfully sent using the following protocol: smtp
User-Agent: CodeIgniter
Date: Sun, 26 Aug 2012 01:50:52 +0200
From: "Free Interesting Articles" 
Return-Path:
```

As you can see there are no errors, but i never recieve the email..
Ive setup the mercury mailserver that comes with xampp, and it logs every mail i send, but i dont recieve any emails at all.

Does anyone have any idea's on how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

to fix this you need to use your computer ip, port forward the port 25 and 110. Then you need to go to the php.ini and click ctrl f and then search: mail function. Then change that ip to your local computer ip. You can find this by typing ip config. Then you need to type that ip where it asks for mail server. Then you need to put send mail from as local email account you've created in mercury. The email account need to look something like: (username@computerip). Then you will save the file and go to the dirrectory: C:\xampp\sendmail and then click sendmail.ini and do the same thing as you did in php.ini accept it will be at the top of the file. Then save the file. Also in mercury, check the setting send relay non local mail. After that you should be able to use the php mail() function and send php email's. That's it you shouldn't have any more problems. Make sure to remove your current config and then do this.